# Spring + Maven | 404 Error: The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, http-status-code-404

Using Eclipse Neon, I'm following the simple Spring Hello World tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#initial), but I'm getting a 404 error. This is a Maven project.

You can see my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/acs254/SpringFrameworkHello). The project builds, and the server (Tomcat v7.0) starts just fine. But when I go to http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/, http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/greeting, or http://localhost:8080/greeting, I get the 404 error.

Can anyone help explain why, and how I can fix the error?

Comment: What if you tried :  http://localhost:8080/SpringHelloWorld/greeting

Comment: No, doesn't work

Comment: Can you hit `localhost:8080/greeting`? I only see `/greeting` as a RequestMapping path.

Comment: Tried it -- doesn't work.

Comment: @acs254 No. I don't want to see your code in GitHub. Please sort out and share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And I hope you understand what [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) is.

Comment: @acs254 I have posted an answer please check and mark correct if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this projects(pom) already contains inbuilt tomcat so You don't need to run this on separate server. Just build using

mvn clean install

java -jar target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

And now check end point it will work.